# Why does my profanity filter not work?

Tags: java, list, string

```
List<String> cursewords = new ArrayList<String>();
cursewords.add("darn it");
cursewords.add("gosh");
cursewords.add("gee whiz");
cursewords.add("golly");

String text = " Golly ";

if (cursewords.contains(text.trim().toLowerCase())  {
    System.out.println("found curse:" + text);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

My filter is not catching things it needs to.

Comment: Does the code you posted work?  Looks okay to me.  I'm confused by the "not catching" bit.

Comment: in this scenario what does text.trim().toLowerCase() return?

Comment: @duffymo: I think Donut's comment below hits on the problem. I need some way to check for the existence of a `cursewords` entry **anywhere** in `text`.

Comment: For the record, you may want to check out this article by Jeff regarding filters http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html

Comment: Thanks for making my day with your list of awful swear words :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your filter will currently only work if `text` is identical to one of the entries in `cursewords` (with no other characters at all). To fix it, you need to instead iterate through the items in `cursewords` and check to see if `text` contains it.

Here's a simple example (uses an [enhanced `for` loop](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/the-enhanced-for-loop.html)):

```
// Convert the string to lowercase here, instead of within the loop
string lowerCaseText = text.toLowerCase();

for (String curse : cursewords) {
    if (lowerCaseText.contains(curse)) {
       System.out.println("found curse:" + curse);
    }
}
```

Although as others have mentioned, it would probably be better to use regular expressions to account for variations in curses and avoid [clbuttic mistakes](http://revealingerrors.com/clbuttic).

Comment: I think that's the problem. I need some way to check for the existence of a `cursewords` entry anywhere in `text`.

Comment: Updated with a simple example.

Comment: This seems fairly inefficient - What if text is the entire contents of a book?  It means you'd be checking against a huge String for each iteration.  Why not split text into individual words and then compare each word against the set of curse words?

Answer (score 1):

List.contains() will look for the exact match.

Maybe you need to do this:

```
for(String curseword:cursewords) {
    //wrong
    //if(curseword.contains(text.trim().toLowerCase())) {
    if(text.trim().toLowerCase().contains(curseword)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You have this backwards.  Should be: if (text.trim().toLowerCase().contains(curseword) { ... }, otherwise the original code would have worked, because you are assuming that the text is already split into individual words.

Comment: -1, there _is_ an exact match. " Golly " gets trimmed to "Golly" and reduced to lowercase "golly"; "golly" is also the last word added to the list `cursewords`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't catch that.  I was assuming the text would be something to the effect of "Oh Golly."

Answer (score 1):

Your code had an error on this line:

```
if (cursewords.contains(text.trim().toLowerCase())  {
```

Enclose your `if` statement with a `)` like so:

```
if (cursewords.contains(text.trim().toLowerCase()))  {
```

**Result**, the code provided now works:

> found curse: Golly

Answer (score 0):

RegEx filters are a better way to look for curse works since f****k or a****muncher might have multiple different middle parts. Look at the [Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class and [Mattcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class for hints on how to write a curse word filter.

Comment: This would catch fork and applemuncher

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not the same as a regular expression.  It assumes that you've already parsed your phrase into individual words.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already pointed out the bug in your code.  However, One general improvement would be to use a stemmer to pre-process the text and then compare the output to a **more manageable** set of "root" curse words.  For example, the stem of "flipping" would be "flip".  Then, instead of checking the entire text each time against every curse word, iterate over each pre-processed word in the text and check whether it is equal to any one of your stemmed curse words.

Other more obvious pre-processing measures would be to remove all punctuation and make all text lower-case.

```
Set<String> stemmedCurseWords = new HashSet<String>();
stemmedCurseWords.add("flip");
stemmedCurseWords.add("gosh");

String text = "I was flipping late for work again."
boolean foundCurseWord = false;

String[] stemmedText = preprocess(text);
for (String word : stemmedText) {
  if (stemmedCurseWords.contains(word)) {
    foundCurseWord = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (foundCurseWord) {
  System.err.println("Bad manners");
}
```